# How to repeat the largest element in a list by the length of the list

Tags: python, list

Write a Python function called all_change_to_max_end that takes as input a list of integers, determines which is larger, the first or last element in the list, and then sets all the other elements to be that value. Output the changed list.

Sample inputs and output:

```
all_change_to_max_end([1, 2, 4, 9, 3]) # should be [3, 3, 3, 3, 3] 

all_change_to_max_end([11, 5, 9])      # should be [11, 11, 11] 

all_change_to_max_end([2, 11])         # should be [11, 11]
```

I've tried using:

```
def all_change_to_max_end(a_list):

    return max(a_list) * len(a_list)
```

but this does not work as it multiples the largest number by the total length

```
all_change_to_max_end([2, 10, 4, 8]

40
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What about `[max(a_list)] * len(a_list)`?

Comment: You do realize that the answer you accepted is neither a function, and it doesn't return the maximum _between the first and last value_?

Comment: Yes, I realized this shortly after testing it. I clearly did not read the question properly

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the max of these two elements (first and last)

```
def all_change_to_max_end(a_list):
    return [max(a_list[0], a_list[-1])] * len(a_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is: `[max(a_list[-1], a_list[0])] * len(a_list)`.

Comment: max between the first and last element has to be selected

Answer (score 0):

Pass a list in this function:

```py
def all_change_to_max_end(x):
    #select maximum and converting it to list
    return [max(x[0], x[-1])]*(len(x)) 

numbers = [1, 5, 8, 4, 3, 7, 9, 7]

print(all_change_to_max_end(numbers))
```

> Out[79]: [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]

Comment: [max(x[1], x[-1]) for i in range(len(x))] 
It will compute max everytime when loops runs so it's good to save it

Comment: `x[1]` is the second element of `x`, not the first.

Comment: Rookie mistake. It's changed now. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

Do this change

When you do max(list) it returns a value not a list so multiplying it to a number is simple multiplication.

```
max(list) * len(list) #let max = 10 and length = 4, then its output is 40
```

so do

```
[max(list[0],list[-1])]
```

This is sample output

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 4, 9, 3]
>>> def all_change_to_max_end(a_list):
...     return [max(a_list[0],a_list[-1])] * len(a_list)
...
>>> all_change_to_max_end(a)
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do :

```
def all_change_to_max_end(l):
    a = l[0]
    b = l[-1]
    return [max(a,b)] * len(l)

print(all_change_to_max_end([11, 5, 9]))
```

output

```
[11, 11, 11]
```